# How can I store a block of text with links in my DB?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textarea (as a description), I want to store the HTML code of the textarea in my db and I can convert the text to HTML with the "br" and "a" tags, the only ones I need. My problem is with the links that have &.

With JS, I tried to use btoa() method to encode the string, store it in my DB and decode with atob() when I want to show it but it gives me this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Is this a Javascript problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: There's no need to encode it. Just store it as it is.

Comment: @NicoHaase i can store links without the &, so I think the problem is with PHP, when I try to insert, preventing SQL injection i think it doesn´t work because of the &

Comment: "i think it doesn´t work " sounds like you should **check** why something is not working. As you haven't shared any code, nor any debugging attempts, it's pretty difficult to tell what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with a string replace before inserting it in the table, and where I want to show, replace it again by `&`.